# PassportJS Profile Undefined Name

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org) and [passport-google-oauth](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth) in an ExpressJS web app.

```
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: CALLBACK
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log(profile.displayName);
  console.log(profile.name.familyName);
  console.log(profile.name.givenName);
  ...
}));
```

The problem is that `profile.displayName`, `profile.name.familyName` and `profile.name.givenName` are undefined. When I use the callback with [Passport Facebook](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/), no problem at all.

How to get the name of the user when using a Google account to login?

Comment: just print profile to find out what are the members of that object are available. (e.g., `console.log(profile);`)

Answer (score 6):

When I checked it seems it has more parameters than what is in the official sample leading people to confusion including me..

rather than

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
```

use

```
function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done)
```

Comment: godlike post for profile undefined and profile.emails[0].value = undefined problem, please mark as solution or upvote. After this, console.log(profile) works. I am working on a facebook flow.

Answer (score 1):

you need to request for it, include `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'` in your scope.

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: CALLBACK,
  scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','email', ...]
}
```